# Spring cloud stream: Headers kafka_acknowledgment value is null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am trying to have the control over the offset commit on kafka topic according to the status of processing of message in the application. If message are successful, so offset can be committed. For this I am trying to get the Headers in my method if so that message can be acknowledge manually

```
  spring:
   cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        contentType: application/json
      default-binder: binder1-kafka
      bindings:
        myChannel:
          binder: binder1-kafka
          destination: my_topic
          content-type: text/plain
          consumer:
            autoCommitOffset: false

        outChannel:
          binder: binder2-kafka
          destination: my_topic
          content-type: text/plain
          consumer:
            autoCommitOffset: false    


      binders:
        #Connection config to different clusters
        binder1-kafka:
          type: kafka
          defaultCandidate: true
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: some-url1:9092
        binder2-kafka:
          type: kafka
          defaultCandidate: false
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: some-url2:9092
```

But When using the listener as

```
@StreamListener(target = IBrokerChannel.myChannel )
public void handlePayload(@Payload MyPayload payload, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) {
  Acknowledgment acknowledgment= (Acknowledgment) headers.get("kafka_acknowledgment"); // acknowledgment object is always null.
  acknowledgment.acknowledge();
}
```

`acknowledgment` is always `null`. I am using kafka producer cli to send the message to the topic. `spring-boot` version is `1.5.10.RELEASE`

Comment: any solutions to this issue? @Pradeep Kr Kaushal

Comment: @beginner_coder. Yes watch the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `kafka` branch in your configuration property definition. It must be like this:

```
spring:
   cloud:
    stream:
      default-binder: kafka
      kafka:
         bindings:
           myChannel:
             consumer:
               autoCommitOffset: false
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Fishtown.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#kafka-consumer-properties

Comment: Applied it. Now listener is not picking up the message :( . And in my application I have the binder to multiple cluster also.

Comment: Well, I showed you only how to fix this particular `autoCommitOffset` property - everything rest has to stay the same. Although you might need to re-check with the Docs if all your properties are in right branch.

Comment: I just tested it without any problems - see my answer.

Comment: @Artem: I edited the config details which is in my app.

Comment: Well, you are still missing `Kafka` branch for the `autoCommitOffset` property...

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So51159949Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So51159949Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so51159949", "foo".getBytes());
        };
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void in(String in, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {
        System.out.println(in);
        System.out.println(headers);
        Acknowledgment ack = headers.get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
        ack.acknowledge();
    }

}
```

and

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          group: so51159949
          destination: so51159949
      kafka:
        bindings:
          input:
            consumer:
              auto-commit-offset: false
```

and

```
foo
{kafka_offset=2, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@4ad39b5f, deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=so51159949, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1530643662028, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = so51159949, partition = 0, offset = 2, CreateTime = 1530643662028, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 3, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = [B@700c9aa9), contentType=application/json}
```

Comment: I edited the question. I put the config suggested by you, still no luck. Have a look again at the question.

Comment: As Artem said, you are still missing `kafka:` in the path of the `autoCommitOffset` property. This is a kafka-specific setting not a general consumer setting.

Comment: i am getting this as an unknown property in eclipse could you please help

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments. Ask a new question showing code and config.